# Text, divs and two smoking floats

Tags: html, css, textbox, css-float

I'm trying to make a #container hold a slideshow and a description of the web-site. However, I want the text in the description to stay to the right of the slideshow until it becomes too tight and moves under the slideshow (so this way it looks good on tablets/phones too). How could I achieve this?
Because so far I had to style the following:

```
    #container {
     height: 900px;
     position: relative;
     width: 98%;
     right: 1%; left: 1%;}

    #slideshow {
     width: 650px;
     height: 450px;
     float:left;
     position: absolute;
     left: 1%;
     overflow: hidden;}

    #description-box {
     position: absolute;
     right: 1%;
     float: right;
     margin-left: 15px;}

    p.description {
    margin-left: 610px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    text-align: justify;}
```

First, the problem is that I don't like the margin-left: 610px for the description that I had to use since the slideshow changes on resizing of the window (at least used to last time I checked). Secondly, I believe I have to many unnecessary styling parameters over all, and it doesn't even do what I need it to!

So, my question is: how can I have a slideshow and the description box sit side by side if there is enough space, but when resized - make the description box move under the slideshow, without the text looking weird and going bananza?

Comment: Take a look at [CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

Comment: Okay, I know this a little bit. But what do I need to change to make the slideshow div and the description div to float together or to be one under the other? Would the min-width work? 
And the other thing I don't like is having to use the margin on p.description. I basically want the two divs to float side by side, but the <p> tags seem to mess everything up for me!

Comment: Basically you should have a media query saying "above this pixel width, float the `#slideshow` and `#description-box` containers." A min-width query would do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, thought so. But then I'm afraid that having different pixel size of em would ruin everything. So, if I specify the media query width, but the text is bigger due to the different em/px ratio - the text would be out of the box and all over the place. Right? I believe I can just omit those users just now though

Comment: @sholanozie Okay. For some reason the text keeps going behind my slideshow, even though I have display: block; Ufff!

Comment: Sorry, I was just on my lunch break. Basically, the idea is to have multiple sets of rules for your elements that "kick in" at different sizes. So, at larger sizes your text might be justified and 600px, but at smaller sizes you might decide that you want it to be left-aligned and 100% of the parent container's width. Play around with the styles at different window sizes and see how you want them to be positioned. Send me an e-mail if you need more extensive help -- you can find my address in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a media query:

```
<!-- you can use max-width or min-width it all depends on the size of the mobile device-->

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    #description-box {
        position: (insert relative or...);
    }
};
```